# Displaying a single item at the top once, before the looping starts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am switching all my infinitely long scrollviews into recycler views. This however makes some things a lot harder.

This is my helperclass for the recycler view:

```
namespace BookOfLife.Screens.Helpers
{
    class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imageView { get; set; }
        public TextView txtDescription { get; set; }

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView):base(itemView)
        {
            txtDescription = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.RecView_Profile_TaskName);
            imageView = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        }
    }

    class RecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        private List<DataForProfile> lstData = new List<DataForProfile>();

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataForProfile> lstData)
        {
            this.lstData = lstData;
        } 

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get
            {
                return lstData.Count;
            }
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {

            RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
            viewHolder.txtDescription.Text = (lstData[position].description);
            viewHolder.imageView.SetImageBitmap((lstData[position].img));
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
            View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecView_Profile, parent, false);
            return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    }



    public class DataForProfile
    {
        public int imageId { get; set; }
        public Bitmap img { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }

    }
```

THE PROBLEM:

I also need to display a certain item at the top of the recycler view that only shows up ONCE. Like a header of some sort. I have not been able to figure out how to do that.

This is my code from where I initialize the RC View:

```
 private void initRecView()
    {

        RecyclerView recycler;
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


        startNumberOfTask = 0;

        List<KumulosHelper.Objects.Picture> pictures = 
            KumulosHelper.Pictures.getNewestXPhotosFromUserInRange
            (strUsername, "4", startNumberOfTask.ToString(), "0"); // 4 Bilder werden momentan nur reingeladen!


        foreach (var picture in pictures)
        {
            startNumberOfTask++;

            var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;

            lstData.Add(new DataForProfile()
            {
                imageId = startNumberOfTask,
                img = (Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap
                (KumulosGeneral.DecodePhotoFromBase64(picture.photo),
                metrics.WidthPixels, metrics.WidthPixels, true)),
                description = picture.taskId.ToString()
            });


        }

        recycler = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recview);
        recycler.HasFixedSize = true;
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(lstData);
        recycler.SetAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

In my AXML Layoutfile, I only have a layout for the constantly repeating images that follow.

THanks!

Comment: `need to display a certain item at the top of the Recyclerview that only shows up ONCE` . Make a single row statically on top of your Recyclerview and populate it with the first row item.

Comment: The problem ist, that it needs to be clickable and there will be some buttons in there and all. would this still work when done statically?